# Extract date from date and time

Tags: c++, date, extract, tdatetime

I am using a VCL forms application in C++ Builder.

How can I get just the date from a TDateTime object that has both a date and a time associated with it?

Here is an example:

```
TDateTime test("25/09/2012 12:00am");
```

I am after a TDateTime object that has just the following information:

```
"25/09/2012"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/DateUtils.DateOf)

However, note that it will return `"25/09/2012 00:00"` as `TDateTime` type includes the time, so if you really need `TDateTime` returned you can't avoid the hour:minute info.

If you want to extract day/month/year info from `TDateTime` you can use [`DecodeDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/SysUtils.DecodeDate) function